# Filter objects across multiple tables in Django database mapper

Tags: django, django-models

I have a relationship model that looks something like:

```
User
 |-1 to n
 Orders
  |- 1 to n
  Items
```

And I want to retrieve all items by a user. Is that possible by only getting it "the Django way" or do I have to fall back to normal SQL?

Sorry to clarify: I could obviously iterate through the order by user and then through the items and add them into a new object. But starting at the Item level, ie:

```
Items.objects.filter(???)
```

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is what you want, but check this:

```
myUser = User.objects.get(pk = 100)
your_items = Items.objects.filter(order__user = myUser)
```